# The set of matrices of form $A^3+B^3$ with multiplication is a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, monoid

> Consider the set
>   \begin{equation*}
> M=\{A^3+B^3|A,B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\}
> \end{equation*}
>   for $n\geq 1$. Prove that $(M,\cdot\;)$ is a monoid.

This is a problem I found in a section of "extra problems" in the romanian magazine Gazeta Matematica, given as a high school problem.

As mentioned in the comment, we need to show that for any complex matrices $A, B, C, D$, one needs to write

$$(A^3 + B^3)(C^3+D^3)$$

as $E^3 + F^3$ for some complex matrices $E, F$. Even in the case $n=1$, I can't algebraically find $e, f\in \mathbb C$ so that 
$$(a^3+ b^3)(c^3+d^3) = e^3+f^3$$
for any given $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Can you show us your efforts, please?

Comment: Edited it. The best thing I have is an attempt to express traces using eigenvalues but didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: The only challenge is to prove that $(A^3+B^3)(C^3+D^3)$ can be written as $X^3+Y^3$. Reminds me of [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) ($\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$ being non-commutative might cause some issues).

Comment: The domain here must be relevant, because this _doesn't_ hold over $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, so it can't be a straightforward identity.

Comment: Yes. It seems like the problem resumes to proving that $(a^3+b^3)(c^3+d^3)$ can be writen as $e^3+f^3$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: (Proof: take $n=1$; then $2$ is a sum of two cubes, but $2\cdot 2=4$ can't be, by case analysis)

Comment: @AndreiCataron _every_ number $x$ can be written as $e^3+f^3$ where $e,f\in\mathbb{C}$; just take $e=0$ and $f$ to be a cube root of $x$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You are right. I think this solves it, doesn't it?

Comment: No, that only solves it for $n=1$. Once you go above that, everything breaks down in that argument.

Comment: Can you give more information about the genesis of this problem? It's clearly a long way from trivial, and having more information about what you're 'supposed' to know in order to handle it (assuming it's a homework question, which it certainly reads like from the PSQ format) would help in giving angles to tackle it. (As would showing your efforts, as the original commentor notes.)

Comment: Probably we could somehow use the fact that diagonalisible matrices form a dense subset.

Comment: It is not a homework problem. I found it in a section of "extra problems" in the romanian magazine Gazeta Matematica. It is given as a high school problem, but you can use any linear algebra knowledge without any problems.

Comment: Well, regardless, @AndreiCataron, you're not going to learn this material, nor how to solve questions like this by ordering us to prove it for you, now will you?  All questions need to include some context, homework or not.  As it is, it is phrased (in the imperative, and all) like a homework problem.

Comment: Questions posted to math.stackexchange.com should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. That can make people wonder if someone copied a question without understanding it. You can ask for help understanding a question, or you can say specifically what difficulties you had solving a problem, but merely copying is frowned on.  Please also read [How to ask a good question on MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @AndreiCataron As suggested in the comment, you may try to provide some context in the question. You've provided some via the comment and I've edited it into the question. You can also edit your question by clicking "edit" just under your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X$ be a complex square matrix. Then $X-tI$ is invertible for some $t>0$. As every invertible complex matrix has a matrix logarithm, $X=A^3+B^3$, where $A=\exp(\frac13\log(X-tI))$ and $B=t^{1/3}I$. Hence $M=\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$. That is, matrix multiplication is closed in $M$. Associativity of matrix multiplication and existence of identity element should be clear.

Comment: I had thought about surjectivity of $\exp$ on invertible matrices, but couldn't make it. Very nice !

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the answer and I'm sorry for not asking corectly the question.